# Knockout afterRender fires too early

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've some knockout bindings specified.
I need to run some script after the whole page is rendered.

```
<div class="row-fluid" data-bind="foreach: { data: rows, afterRender: myCallback }">
</div>
```

Unfortunately, `myCallback` is called too early - not all DOM elements are rendered and size of element's are not calculated yet (what's more, myCallback need to call init function of plugging, that requires all elements size to be calculated)

How can I call `myCallback` when all DOM elements on page are rendered (and bindings are applied)?

**UPDATE**
I've wrote a little hack:

```
<div class="location-map-div" data-bind="openLayers: Value, attr: { style: 'width: 50%; height: 200px' }" style="width:100px; height:100px"></div>
```

I've set inline style, so my plugin is able to initalize, and then change size with knockout binding.

Comment: What plugin are you using?  And what is this "init" method you mentioned -- is it a custom binding handler?  What does it look like?

Comment: It's OpenLayers. I need to call updateSize() on map, but it tells mi that height/width of the element is undefined. When I call it from firebug console after all element render, it works. It happens beceause my div has 100% width (so real is size is not calculated yet when appyling bindigns)

Answer (score 0):

afterRender is called for each element in your 'rows' array. You should check if you're on the last element.

```
<div class="row-fluid" data-bind="foreach: { data: rows, afterRender: thenDoStuff }">
</div>

viewModel.lastItem = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.items()[this.items().length - 1];
}, viewModel);

viewModel.thenDoStuff = function(elements, data) {
    if (data === viewModel.lastItem()) {
        alert('last one!');
        var parent = $(elements).filter('li').parent();
    }
};
```

Here is an example I found and modified to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6yqq/8/

Comment: It's too early. I need to have whole page rendered, not only list.  I've tried to make a special div:
`<div data-bind="template: {  afterRender: thenDoStuff }">
</div>` (that wraps whole page), but then theDoStuff is called before item render..

Comment: Nope. I've noticed that element's (that are used in foreach binding) size are not calculated in doc ready.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom binding that calls an event during the render process :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.onRender = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var events = ko.unwrap(value);

       if(events.once)
           events.once.call();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var events = ko.unwrap(value);

       if(typeof events == 'function')
          events.call();

        if(events.each)
           events.each.call();
    } 
};
```

The binding should be used as follow :

```
<div data-bind="onRender:{once: firstCall, each: eachCall}"/>
```

Every times knockout will render this div, the eachCall function will be called.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9f3u/)

Comment: Unfortunately - it's also called before rendering template items.

Comment: I mean inner `div` with `foreach` binding.